# Is there any API or command line to get P4 Swarm Review for a given p4 Change

Tags: perforce, swarm

I am trying to get P4 Swarm review Id from given Change.
can any one help to provide command line or API to get p4 swarm reviews from P4 change.

I tried to check P4 command lines and trying to find APIs

Answer (score 0):

Using the Swarm API, you can query the `reviews` endpoint with a `change` parameter, e.g.:

```
https://your.swarm.instance/api/v11/reviews?change=NNNNNN
```